# exporting .olm file to csv on Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, csv

I am using outlook on mac and trying to export .OLM file and convert it to CSV file for analysis purpose. Any idea how to transform outlook .OLM file into CSV?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can export items to .olm file. For more information, please refer to: [Export items to an archive file in Outlook for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-items-to-an-archive-file-in-outlook-for-mac-281a62bf-cc42-46b1-9ad5-6bda80ca3106).

However, according to my research and testing, as far as outlook for Mac client is concerned, I didn't find a method to directly convert .olm file into .csv file. I'm afraid you need to use some third-party software.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.